# Is there a possibility of selecting a specific range of data on excel using VBA code based of a column criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

In my data set, I have a column with a large number of email addresses, some repeating, some not.

I have inserted a new column to the right where I've copied the same list and removed duplicates.

I want to be able to use the list of removed duplicates to loop through the full column of emails and grab the data in the rows for each repetition of that email and paste that data into an email body send the email to that contact.  Then, when there are no more repetitions of the first email in the list, it moves on to the next email in the list and does the same for each until it's gone through the complete list.

Is this something that's possible? My VBA experience is limited, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes its possible.  To get a more detailed answer see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't quite sure how to word the question I was looking to ask without making it too long.

Answer (score 0):

This is very doable in VBA. The best bet would be to either create an Access Database with a table that documents every time you send an e-mail to a certain e-mail address.  That way you can check that list before generating another e-mail.  It would work like this-> 1. Check to see if the e-mail is in the table. 2. If it is, then go to the next e-mail. 3.  If it isn't insert the email into your table and send an e-mail.  You could do this with a spreadsheet too, but I would prefer to use a table for this kind of thing.  This table could be expanded upon to make a log as to when and what you sent to each user.

Comment: I already have the portion of code to create the outlook email, and populate it for the most part. I can create and send an email for each individual row of data, but some customers have upwards of 50-100+ invoices and I'd rather not bombard them with mass amounts of emails and be able to send a summary. I've thought about recording, but it's not quite feasible with what I'm looking to happen.

Comment: So are you worried mainly about using the same e-mail twice?

Comment: Correct. Instead of sending X number of emails to the same address (even though the information attached in the body of each email sent would be different on each email. Each invoice has it's own row in the excel worksheet, but the contact it's sent to may be the same because that company has more than 1 outstanding invoice) I'm trying to summarize it all in one email.

Comment: Hopefully, this answer is more appropriate for your question.